# How to convert my dictionary query to properly formatted string without getting garbage?

Tags: python

Assume this is my dictionary:

```
dc = { 0 : { "name" : "A", "value" : 4}, 1 : {"name" : "B", "value" : 5}, 2: {"name" : "C", "value" : 7}}
```

I need to transform all values from keys `value` into a string formatted like this:

```
(4, 5, 7)
```

Format is mandatory (this is some robotic automation) - series of integers, separated by `,`  and surrounded by `()`. No other garbage.

Good examples:

```
()
(1)
(1, 5, 15, 37, 123, 56874)
```

Bad examples:

```
[4, 5, 7]
{4, 5, 7}
('4', '5', '7')
(1,)
```

My naive approach was "lets iterate over all dictionary items, collect all "values" into `tuple` and then `str` it", but tuples cannot be modified. So I said "ok, collect to list, convert to tuple and then str":

```
res = list()
for item in dc.values():
    res.append(item['value'])
print(str(tuple(res)))
```

I'm new to Python and I bet there is more elegant way of doing this, but it worked fine for multi-item and empty results. However, if my query returns only single item, then Python adds an extra empty item and it breaks the robotic client.

```
>>>>str(tuple([4]))
(4,)
```

Is there way of not getting this empty extra without explicit checking `if len(res)==1`?

Actually, is there more robust and elegant way of cutting out all `value`s into strictly formatted string as I need?

Comment: I see this was closed for being a duplicate even though the other question doesn't exactly answer yours. To properly format it no matter the number of elements, you can use an f-string and some python black magic to join all the elements with commas and surround with parentheses: `f'({", ".join(map(str, res))})'`

Comment: @Adid I'm looking for a duplicate target which answers the string joining part of the question; it is better to close such questions sooner rather than let them accrue many duplicated answers.

Comment: Yes someone closed just by judging by title, without getting into details. God bless fast bashing admins.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use one line generator:

```
tuple(item['value'] for item in dc.values())
#(4, 5, 7)
```

If you just have 1 value you can add `[0]` at the end:

```
tuple(item['value'] for item in dc.values())[0]
#4
```

Else you will get like:

```
(4,)
```

If you have 1 value and you want string datatype then:

```
str(tuple(item['value'] for item in dc.values())[0])
#'4'
```

**Edit:**

You can try:

```
'(' + ', '.join(str(item['value']) for item in dc.values()) + ')'
```

for single value:

```
#'(4)'
```

for multiple values:

```
#'(4, 5, 7)'
```

Comment: `>>>> dc1
{0: {'name': 'A', 'value': 4}}
>>>> tuple(item['value'] for item in dc1.values())
(4,)`

Comment: add a zero. `tuple(item['value'] for item in dc.values())[0]` `#4`

Comment: if I add [0] it only returns the integer, no (). And doesn't work for longer or empty queries.

Comment: Latest modification works! Thank you sir